# Different UIFonts in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to make an app that will let users select different fonts and rotate them around as desired.

- What I need to know is what technology is being used in this app (see screenshots below)?
- Is it UIKit, CATextLayer?
- Are these texts / fonts available out of the box in apples UIKit module?
- How can you let user resize or rotate text fonts.

[image]

[image]

Is there any sample apple project or sample code in github that I can use to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that looks like it can be done with custom fonts, none of them will be found in UIKit. You'll need to buy or find fonts that you have the rights to distribute. [Here's a good reference for adding custom fonts to your project](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/load-and-access-custom-fonts.html).

Once you have fonts installed.  UILabel and other text holding controls can have their .font properties queried and set.  And anything else you'd like to do to a view (like set up a rotational transform) is applicable to those controls, too.

Comment: thanks for the pointer danh. There are a lot of app out there that use custom fonts so I assume its something that is readily available i.e. either free or for purchase.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but @danh any reason why this can be done with custom fonts and not those found within the device itself?

Comment: @BradMoore, my understanding is that it's okay to use fonts apple distributes with iOS.  I think you're getting license to those when you buy your developer license.

Comment: @danh oh, I thought you were saying it can _only_ be done with custom fonts, not that the fonts displayed in the images above are custom fonts so you'd also need to use custom fonts. That makes a heap more sense now I read everything after some good sleep :)